# Как удалить ссылку в заголовке столбца GridView yii2

Tags: yii2, gridview

Как удалить ссылку в заголовке (ранжирование столбца) столбца GridView yii2
нужно что бы был просто текст
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Перед GridView::widget ставим  `$dataProvider->sort = false;`